# Image getting corrupted while downloading via wget. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, image, wget

[image]

This image gets corrupted when I'm trying to download using wget. I'm completely not sure where I'm going wrong. This is my code:

```
command = 'wget '  + '-U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17"'  + image + ' -O ' + path

                ssh.exec_command(command)
                command = 'mogrify -auto-orient ' + path
                ssh.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: Please add url of the image you are trying.

Comment: Does it corrupt when you download *without* python?

Answer (score 0):

A priori you are doing right with `-U` and agent string of browser.

This worked for the asker [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24935/wget-downloads-corrupt-jpeg-file) :

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 
Safari/534.17" http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg
```

So you may make sure that what you have in your pasted code as `+ image + ' -O ' + path` actually is in a url form as `http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg`